# Is there a way to pop up and dismiss screen like this in flutter?

Tags: flutter, mobile, flutter-animation

[image: Modal sheet]

I am familiar with how to do this in Swift, but is there a way to achieve the same result in Flutter? The screen should "popup" from the bottom and could be dismissed by swiping down.

Comment: See https://pub.dev/packages/modal_bottom_sheet

Answer (score 2):

There are a bunch of 3rd-party widgets to do it. They don't look exactly the same as the one described but they are highly customizable. Here are some from https://pub.dev/

1. [awesome_select](https://pub.dev/packages/awesome_select)
2. [backdrop_modal_route](https://pub.dev/packages/backdrop_modal_route)
3. [bottom_sheet_expandable_bar](https://pub.dev/packages/bottom_sheet_expandable_bar)
4. [bottom_sheet](https://pub.dev/packages/bottom_sheet)
5. [cupertino_modal_sheet](https://pub.dev/packages/cupertino_modal_sheet)
6. [enter link description here](https://pub.dev/packages/modal_bottom_sheet)
7. [just_bottom_sheet](https://pub.dev/packages/just_bottom_sheet)
8. [sheet](https://pub.dev/packages/sheet)